# Want to find a book/story about men who went to moon and somehow ate crystals found there

Tags: story-identification

The children of the men after they returned to Earth were special and one created a anti-gravity device from drawing a circuit with pencil on plywood, then used a warm beer can as the power source.

Comment: Off to a good start, but we're going to need some more details, such as when you may have read it or when it was published. If you haven't already, take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can [edit] in any more details

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like it could be "[The Moon Children](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00EEBKPCE)" by Jack Williamson.

> An international agency, COSMOS, is in charge of space exploration in the not very distant future. Odd forms of life have been discovered on Mars, Venus, and Jupiter; there may be a life form on Mercury; and finally something utterly mystifying is discovered on the moon. Three astronauts land and examine an installation that all three perceive as radically different - one sees a heap of gold, one a fort bristling with guns, one a space platform and space craft. They return to Earth with some crystals picked up at the mystery site.
>
> All three soon produce children - the moon children, gifted, precocious, and seemingly damned by the crystals their fathers had handled. Two are eerily beautiful, the third a grotesque monster. And the three soon discover that they are Earth's hope for survival, as interplanetary invasion brings overwhelming alien forces to bear on mankind.